# What did post-vocalic r sound like in the UK before it died out?

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change, rhoticity

As far as I understand it most UK dialects became non-rhotic at some point in the 19th century - but was the r sound previously heard in words like *park* similar to today's American pronunciation, or if not what did it sound like?

Comment: Which pronunciation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, there are still UK dialects today which are rhotic, especially in the West Country, Scotland, and Northern Island (plus the Republic of Ireland which is not in the UK, but in close contact). Scotland uses a trill, but the others use a very similar R to Americans. This gives us some indication.

The evidence seems to suggest that older varieties of British English and American English sounded more like Irish English. Here's a quick video on how they reconstructed Original Pronunciation aka [Shakespearean English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPlpphT7n9s) which was definitely a rhotic dialect.

Comment: I found an 1888 recording of William Gladstone (https://archive.org/details/EDIS-SRP-0190-12). WG was born in Liverpool in 1809 and educated at Eton and Oxford. The recording isn't very clear but the accent is definitely rhotic. The r sound does seem more like modern Irish English than modern American English. On the same site there is an 1890 recording of the bugler of Charge of the Light Brigade fame (b. 1834 in Gibraltar). He sounds even more Irish but it is possible he spent part of his childhood in Dublin. OTOH Arthur Sullivan (b. 1842, London) has a non-rhotic accent.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Out of curiosity, is the Lancashire R trilled like the Scottish R?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Those sounds like trills to me.

Comment: @GArthurBrown - not exactly. Listen to 'world' in Gracie Fields singing '[The Biggest Aspidistra in the World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68Dm5L5SyKQ)'